# Каким образом можно, имея в наличии MS Visual C++ 2010, считать сигнал, поступающий на порт?

Tags: порт, c++

Каким образом можно, имея в наличии MS Visual C++ 2010, считать сигнал, поступающий на порт (USB или COM - интересуют оба варианта)? 
Просто считывание, просто двоичного сигнала. В ОС Windows.

Comment: com и usb в общем - это разные порты (если только не включена эмуляция com через usb).

Comment: Мда, когда уже все поймут, что в С++ нет портов, нет дисков, нет цветных мониторов, нет звука и даже курсора нет.

Операционные системы, имеющиеся библиотеки и компиляторы не забываем указывать, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

По USB есть книги Агурова.
Работать с портами можно через CreateFile(), в качестве имени надо указывать специально оформленное имя файла для порта, смотри доки и примеры.

Answer (score 0):

Читать из COM практически то же самое, что и читать из файла.
Примеров масса: [1](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/I-N/network/serialcommunications/article.php/c5425), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/chaiyasit_t.aspx), [3](http://members.ee.net/brey/Serial.pdf).

Читать из USB можно только через драйвер. У USB-устройств может быть множество разных интерфейсов, некоторые из них реализуют интерфейс COM-порта.